# Relatively secure faster alternative for HTTPS

Tags: tls

I am working on a multiplayer game. I intended for all data to be exchanged over HTTPS, but it is way too slow. High latency networks take over a second for SSL handshake. While the game is turn-based and does not require blazing-fast data transfer, 1000-2000 ms ping is still unacceptable.

What protocols/approaches can I use to transfer data securely, with as low latency as possible?

---

Edit: Just to respond to your enquiries about the payload, here is what the result of a unit attacking an enemy building (obviously I'm not sending a string of ones and zeros, this is just a binary representation):

```
00000000 10010011 01010001 00100011 01011100 01010001 01010000
```

Message breakdown:

```
00000000  client's request executed with status "OK", other values correspond to specific error messages.

10        Object is owned by Player 2
010       Object is a building
0110      Object is located at x=6  (always 0<=x<=14)
101       Object is located at y=5  (always 0<=y<=6), owner and location is sufficient to describe any object uniquely
0001      1 byte-worth of modified attributes follows
0010 0011 Object's health is now 3

01        Object is owned by Player 1
011       Object is a unit
1000      Object is located at x=8
101       Object is located at y=5
0001      1 byte-worth of modified attributes follows
0101 0000 This object can no longer move/attack this turn
```

I don't think that I can get any more data density without making it expensive on the CPU.

Comment: HTTPS needs 2 round trips for a full handshake. And 1 round trip for resumption. Both should be well below half a second in most settings. I don't think this should get you into 2 second territory. Further reading: https://istlsfastyet.com/

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Networks like mobile Edge (which I am currently on) can take well over 2 seconds to handle a single GET request.

Comment: Don't know much about it, but maybe [websockets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14711517/1822514)? You can use [websockets over ssl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl)

Comment: as Steffan's answer points out, the format of the data can have a major impact on the communication.  How are these messages being serialized and are you know where your latency is coming from?

Comment: And, as both Phillip and Steffan point out, you shouldn't need to do a handshake on each exchange.  If that's what is happening, you are probably closing the session after each exchange.  If so, you should consider fixing that before moving to something else as well as consider how your payloads are encoded (see comment above.)

Comment: If each of your messages is tiny enough to fit in a single IP packet and you're not saturating any line but generating messages either periodically or upon user action, then you probably won't see *any* performance difference between a format that has a 60 byte message or a 600 byte message, despite one being ten times larger. So you don't need to worry about data density until you start getting to 1kb, 2kb or more.

Comment: @Peteris I am aware. I only brought it up because of others asking about messages I'm trying to send.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff HTTPS uses TCP connection coterminous with TLS connection (vs e.g. IMAP STARTTLS or FTP AUTH TLS) so it's 1 RT for TCP-SYN plus 1 for TLS-abbreviated or *at least 2* for TLS-full: more than 2 if server first flight (mostly cert chain) exceeds the initial congestion window and it usually does.

Comment: If you're not doing browser stuff and just trying to use HTTPS for security; maybe check if ZMQ has baked-in authentication/encryption yet.

Comment: Using *any* flavor of HTTP for a game may be a bad idea overall. You should educate yourself about alternatives, maybe with the help of programming-type SE sites and [gamedev.SE]. (Side note: how many bytes do you get with a gzipped human-readable message? Think about debugging and such.)

Comment: @Peteris I'm asking about format because you can spend a lot of time marshalling and unmarshalling and it can look like latency if you capture timings in the wrong places.

Comment: @JimmyJames the timings were captured after data were packed in the above format and before a request was made, and after the request was completed, right before the data were unpacked. Implementing my own protocol sped things up greatly, effectively removing the latency. It is not yet being done through TLS, so I can't say what the final latency will be with certainty.

Comment: @Mirac7 Are you saying that the latency is gone over HTTP with the new protocol or something else?  On a side note, you might want to avoid gzip on really small messages since it may make them larger.

Comment: @JimmyJames No, I ditched HTTP completely and implemented my own sockets. I am not performing any compression on my messages.

Comment: The nice thing about using HTTPS is that so many people care about it and are heavily invested in it.  If you can't get it to meet your needs, obviously it makes sense to drop to something else.  Please update this with how much latency TLS adds when you get to that and good luck on your project.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

HTTPS is HTTP over [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

If you implement a game, using HTTP is usually not a good idea. The HTTP protocol is designed for requesting documents, not for real-time games. A better idea would be to develop your own protocol directly based on TCP or UDP (UDP is faster while TCP is easier to use, but that's a topic for [game development stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com)) and tunnel it through TLS.

The time-consuming key exchange process only needs to happen once when establishing the connection. When you keep the same connection open during the game, the only latency overhead is caused by encryption and decryption. TLS supports multiple cipher suites (sets of cryptographic algorithms which are used). The choice of cipher suite can be used to find a compromise between performance and security.

Comment: Or just use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), over a `wss://` URL. StackOverflow's chat uses this to communicate.

Comment: The nice thing about rolling your own protocol (other than that it's not insanely slow) is that you don't have to restrict yourself to one option. If you want to accept a direct TCP connection, or a websocket, both with and without TLS, *you can do that*, and some games (eg Furcadia) do that.
This has the disadvantage that a MitM attack could downgrade the connection, but the upside that legacy clients can still connect on the same ports, for now, and the ability to connect unencrypted can be deprecated and eventually phased out, without any players having to change what port they allow out.

Comment: You can also explicitly permit downgraded clients for 3rd party apps, bots and proxies, but in return add extra security constraints ingame. This allows players to easily script 3rd party utils, and makes the downgrade a conscious and visible choice.

Comment: It is not always true that UDP is faster. If you have specific needs that TCP cannot satisfy, and you know what you are doing, then UDP may be faster. With UDP it is easy to introduce amplification vulnerabilities. Those can be very hard to fix after the fact and once attackers find them you can quickly lose any performance benefit you may have gained from using UDP in the first place.

Comment: "A better idea would be to develop your own protocol" -- and that on this site! No, there's probably a library in whatever language they are using for socket communication, and all levels of abstraction upwards.

Answer (score 31):

> High latency networks take over a second for SSL handshake

There should be no need to do a full handshake for each message exchange. The handshake is only needed at start of the TCP connection, thus just leave the connection open. Then the latency is what you have with any other established TCP connection. If you need even less latency at the cost of possible packet loss or duplication use DTLS, i.e. TLS with datagrams (UDP).

Apart from that HTTP(s) might not be the optimal protocol for use on high latency and low bandwidth connections. The encapsulation of the payload in HTTP request and response alone has a non-trivial overhead (depending on the amount of payload) and if you the often used text based payload (i.e. JSON, XML or similar) only adds more overhead. Binary based data exchange (like protobuf or similar) makes much better use of the available resources.

Comment: +1. I would add that slow TLS (e.g. HTTPS) connection times are often due to one end or the other being out of entropy, which is a limited resource in many environments. This is another reason to prefer long lived connections as Steffen suggests, and remember WSS a viable alternative if you need to asynchronously send data to the client (as opposed to work on a strictly request/reply model).

Answer (score 11):

If you want a connection based on TCP, use TLS. Set up the connection in advance, so you pay the 2 RTT latency once and then never need pay it again.  You can use the SPDY extension if you want to reduce the one-time up-front latency cost of initially establishing the connection.

If you want a connection based on UDP, use [DTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security).  This may reduce even more latency, by eliminating TCP's re-transmissions and other things TCP does that can introduce latency in certain circumstances.  Once again, set up the connection in advance, so you pay the 2 RTT latency once and then never need pay it again.